# How to set default tab on page load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

How can I modify the script to have second tab (instead of first) as default when the page loads? Thanks..

```
<script>
$(function() {      
    $("#nav ul").tabs("#panes > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 400});
});
</script>

<!-- tab panes -->
<div id="panes">
    <div>
        <p>content1</p>
    </div>  
     <div>
        <p>content2</p>
     </div>     
</div>


 <!-- navigator -->
<div id="nav">
    <ul>        
        <li>
            <a href="#1">
                Tab1
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#2">
                Tab2
            </a>

        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using? I don't believe there's enough code here to answer your question.

Comment: no plugin - here is where I got it from http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/skin4.htm

Comment: You are not using a pure jQuery library. You're using something called 'jQuery Tools' which combines the jQuery 1.4.2 library with some plugins. So, yes, you are in fact using a plugin... somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your tabs to reflect the following

```
$(function() {      
    $("#nav ul").tabs("#panes > div", {initialIndex: 1, effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 400});
});
```

**EDIT:**

It looks as though your real question pertains to jQuery Tools rather than jQuery UI, as per your example you provided. I have therefore updated my code to match the jQuery Tools documentation found [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html). The issue is, jQuery UI uses something called `selected` to determine the zero-indexed initial tab shown. jQuery Tools by contrast uses something called `initialIndex`. You can find a working example of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nUjRz/).

Comment: For clarity purposes, the `selected` parameter is 0-indexed, so `1` represents the 2nd tab

Comment: Lance - I tried this but still keep getting the first tab on page load. Any suggestions on how to see whats going on?

Comment: @Prateek, this might sound elementary, but have you cleared your browser cache and tried the script?

Comment: @Lance - yes I did - here is where I picked up the original code (with css - just in case that had something to do with it) but still doesn't work. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/skin4.htm  - copied source and used 'selected: 1' in script.

Comment: Are you including `http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js` in your document head somewhere? This file seems to include more than just your basic jQuery + jQuery UI libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Use the selected option.

```
<script>  
  $(function() {            
    $("#nav ul").tabs("#panes > div", {effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: 400, selected:1});  
});  
</script>
```

Check the URL:

> http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#options

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ui-tabs-selected to your second Tab.

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>        
    <li>
        <a href="#1">
            Tab1
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="ui-tabs-selected">
        <a href="#2">
            Tab2
        </a>

    </li>       
</ul>
```

But you have to do some additional css styling