# How to forward control to Div tag using struts-xml file

Tags: java, struts

I am having tabbed HTML with three Tabs.

How can i transfer control to another tabs, i am using Struts 1.3 framework.

```
<action name="AcquisitionForm" path="/Acquition" type="com.woi.action.AcquitionAction" validate="false"> 
       <forward name="pcdemo" path="/Main.jsp#tab2" />
</action>
```

Comment: can u share what effort you have tried to achieve?

Comment: After execut method my control should come to tab2 of my Main.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@niraj deshmukh There is nothing to do with Struts-config.xml file. This will only takes you to the main.jsp page. You got to do some javascript/jQuery works to select second tab. I am not sure what kind of tab you are using. Here i shown the selecting particular(2/3) [jQuery tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 });
});
```

But this code will do everytime tab2 selected. You need to change this code according to your need. Refer this [selecting a specific jquery tab on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603189/i-need-help-selecting-a-specific-jquery-tab-on-page-load) and [default tab on page load using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856109/how-to-set-default-tab-on-page-load-using-jquery) for more information. Hope this help you.